# PHPSESSID always in URL (cookies enabled)

Tags: php

I have a simple authentication script. It will compare posted data from login form to a database table users - if there´s succes I´ll start sesssion by:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] = "1";
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST["user"];
$_SESSION['admin'] = "1";
```

The problem is I always have session ID in URL (cookies are enabled). 
PHP.ini is set like that:

```
session.use_cookie = 1
session.use_only_cookie = 0
session.use_trans_sid = 1
```

And I'm runing it on localhost.

I want my session to prefere getting session ID in cookie - if enabled. Getting session ID in URL shoul by used only if cookies are disabled. I´ve read that should behave like that automatically but it doesn´t.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe miss

`use_trans_sid = 0`

if you enable "use_trans_sid" then the session id is attached to the URL everytime.

Comment: But if trans_sid = 0 then the session doesn´t work at all. Everytime loading s new page the ures is beeing logged out.